# Row level changes captured via AWS DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, cloud, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

I am trying to migrate the database using AWS DMS. Source is Azure SQL server and destination is Redshift. Is there any way to know the rows updated or inserted? We dont have any audit columns in source database.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift doesn’t track changes and you would need to have audit columns to do this at the user level.  You  may be able to deduce this from Redshift query history and save data input files but this will be solution dependent.  Query history can be achieved in a couple of ways but both require some action. The first is to review the query logs but these are only saved for a few days.  If you need to look back further than this you need a process to save these tables so the information isn’t lost.  The other is to turn on Redshift logging to S3 but this would need to be turned on before you run queries on Redshift.  There may be some logging from DMS that could be helpful but I think the bottom line answer is that row level change tracking is not something that is on in Redshift by default.